# Is there a browser that supports IPv6 Link Local addresses?

Tags: ipv6, browser, url

I'd like to know at last one browser that allows me to browse `fe80::4216:7eff:fe9f:79ac%enp2s0f0`, for example. I've checked there're many tickets open in bug trackers of big name browsers like Firefox and Chrome. I know Internet Explorer on Windows is able to provide an option, but I'd like to know anyone on Linux land.

Comment: All browsers support `http://[::1]` as the Link Local self address. None seem to support generic Link Local addresses. Seems to be a problem of scope.

Comment: @user79743 `::1` is not a link-local address.

Comment: In an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31510904/3476849) on Stack Overflow I explained how `ssh` can be used to work around this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Same struggle here. But you can use `lynx`. I tested it with 2.8.9dev1-2+deb8u1 from the debian Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a compromise to the firefox ticket, but the chrome one is closed:

1) LL % addresses won't be processed in the Location bar due to the complexity cited.
2) LL % addresses would be processed in file: hosted HTML, and possibly (with some permission) generated by extensions.

This lets someone build an extension that can do things like mDNS or other browsing that finds IoT devices and generates HTML output that can be clicked on.